# ¿Cómo guardo una variable en la session y utilizo en otro controller en ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy haciendo una llamada a un Web Service ASMX, instancio el WS, el output y hago la llamada.

Lo que me gustaría hacer es guardar el output en la `session` y utilizar mas tarde en otros Controllers los datos que recibí.

Código de la llamada:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Models.HomeViewModels.Login login)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        Byte[] originalBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(login.Contraseña);
        Byte[] encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);

        string hash = BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

        SRWSAPP.WSAPPSoapClient wsWSAPP = new SRWSAPP.WSAPPSoapClient();
        SRWSAPP.Autenticacion outAutenticacion = new SRWSAPP.Autenticacion();
        outAutenticacion = wsWSAPP.AutenticarUsuario(login.Usuario, hash);

        if (outAutenticacion.CodError == 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Informe", "Solicitudes");
        } else {
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: si andas iniciando con ASP.net MVC, te recomiendo este workshop que hice hace unos meses: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY saludos :D

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por tu comentario, y el video me sirvio bastante, saludos

Comment: De nada hermano, estamos para servir :D entre todos nos capacitamos y entre todos compartimos, así todos salimos beneficiados :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para guardar:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionString"] = sessionValue;
```

Para leer variables almacenadas:

```
ViewData["sessionString"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionString"] as String;
```

Para mayor información: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-and-access-447ada98

Answer (score 0):

intenta con:

```
TempData["clave"] = "esta variable perdura entre controladores";
```

Comment: El alcance de TempData es a nivel de Request, quiere decir que unicamente se mantiene vivo en la siguiente petición.

Answer (score 0):

```
Session["variable_sesion"] = outAutenticacion;
```

Comment: Lamentablemente lo que propone Fergie Gauvain, no servirá si quieres tener acceso al dato durante toda la sesión. TempData luego que se haga la próxima llamada (HttpRequest), se perderá el objeto en cuestión.

Answer (score 0):

Yo evitaría lo más posible usar variables de sesión. El protocolo HTTP es "stateless" (sin estado, es decir cada request es independiente del anterior). El framework te da algunas herramientas para solventar eso, pero crea otros problemas al final. Algunas alternativas:

- Si la información está ligada al usuario, guárdala en una base de datos
- Si requieres la información sólo para después del redirect, usa TempData
- Si la información es acotada, puedes incluirla en el redirect:

`RedirectToAction("Informe", "Solicitudes", new { respuesta = "info"});`

Comment: buenas @Francisco y como hago para guardar esa variable en una base de datos?

Comment: El tutorial más actualizado está en inglés https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/ef-mvc/intro.html pero si buscas "entity framework" hay buenos tutoriales en español, por ejemplo https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

Answer (score 0):

Estas realizando un login, no se guarda en Session los datos de autenticacion.

No se como implementas la seguridad en el sitio, si usas: `asp.net membership`, `simplemembership` o `identity`, pero usas Session para la seguridad es incorrecto.

[Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

La idea es que luego de autenticarte uses los `Claims` para guardar info relacionada con la seguridad

[La nueva era de la autentificación: Claims](https://itblogsogeti.com/2015/07/23/la-nueva-era-de-la-autentificacion-claims-amaia-baigorri-sogeti/)